# Does OpenTK work in Windows 8?

Tags: opentk

While looking up OpenTK, I found a couple of references to threads that talk about Windows 8 support:

- [This one from 2011](http://www.opentk.com/node/2691) claims that OpenTK works on a Win8 preview
- [A newer one from 2012](http://svn.opentk.net/node/3114) leaves the question open, and mentions crashes on VMs.

Is there a definitive answer to this?

Comment: DV but no comments?

Comment: Sounds like something you'll have to try out for yourself. There could easily be a grey area when some features are supported and others not. It may also depend on the current hardware the user is using as graphics drivers for Win8 may not be finalized. Additionally any answer here could easily change very quickly, with either a video driver update or a new release of OpenTK.

Comment: Do you mean AppStore Apps (that runs on Win RT, too) or "legacy apps" for the classic desktop (only on Win 8, not RT)?

Comment: @Beachwalker I don't know. I wanted to write an OpenTK game that runs "somehow" on Windows 8. I decided to go with MonoGame instead.

Comment: Want to know something funny? MonoGame actually uses OpenTK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

I'm doing some creative coding on OpenTK's current version on Windows 8, and I can confirm it works just fine.